# PHP SOAP - Expanding __doRequest

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to expand PHP's \SoapClient to include timeout and retry capabilities...I have tried to implement both of the following two scripts without any success

https://github.com/ideaconnect/idct-soap-client/blob/master/src/client.php

https://gist.github.com/RobThree/2490351

The strange thing is, a completely default soap request works perfectly for me.  The following script also works perfectly for me...

```
class SoapTest extends \SoapClient {

    public function __construct($wsdl, $options) {  
        parent::__construct($wsdl,$options);
    }

    public function __doRequest ($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null) {
      $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
      return $response;
    }

}
```

However when I start trying to implement my own __doRequest code I can't get it working no matter the hundred variations I have tried.  Below is one of the snippets I have tried, does anyone know the default options/lines I need to use to make it behave natively?

```
        $curl = curl_init($location);
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(sprintf('Content-Type: %s', $version == 2 ? 'application/soap+xml' : 'text/xml'), sprintf('SOAPAction: %s', $action)),
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $this->sslverifypeer
        );

        if ($this->timeout>0) {
            if (defined('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS')) {    //Timeout in MS supported?
                $options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS] = $this->timeout;
            } else  { //Round(up) to second precision
                $options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = ceil($this->timeout/1000);
            }
        }

        if ($this->connecttimeout>0) {
            if (defined('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS')) { //ConnectTimeout in MS supported?
                $options[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS] = $this->connecttimeout;
            } else { //Round(up) to second precision
                $options[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = ceil($this->connecttimeout/1000);
            }
        }

        if (curl_setopt_array($curl, $options) === false)
            throw new Exception('Failed setting CURL options');

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to ask: what errors you get? Have you logged the values of the vars?  Did you try the example in http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php?

Comment: btw, there are some hints there and some explanations to solve tricky things that could happens you when extending `__doRequest()`

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid to re-invent the wheel. The SoapClient already handles the timeout (see the *connection_timeout* option of the constructor in the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).

Then you can just implement the retries doing something like

```
public function __doRequest ($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null) {
    
    try {
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        // handle the retry
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you attempt at helping.  I provided a bunch of other info but the user decided to delete his answer and thus all my responses.  The issue I have is when I try to assign options (as in my last code sample above) things don't work.  Perhaps I'm missing something in your answer.  Regardless, I'm gonna give you my points cause they are going to waste otherwise.  For some reasons stackoverflow members decided to downvote my questions.....

Comment: Well, thank you for the bounty. Without your other comments I probably missed a part of the scenario.
Anyway, if the problem is in the options, then I would check your version of cUrl and if the constant are all available. Then I would check with or without CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER what happens